# Use Octave in msvc 2010

Tags: c++, octave

I am using Octave within MSVC 2010. First I downloaded Octave latest version at this [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Windows%20binaries/Octave%203.6.4%20for%20Windows%20Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio/). After installing, I tried to run this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<octave-3.6.4\octave\oct.h>
#include<octave-3.6.4\octave\config.h>
#include<octave-3.6.4\octave\octave.h>

using namespace std;


int main (void)
{
  std::cout << "Hello Octave world!\n";   

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
  }
```

Note that I added these links to my project as well:

1. C:\Software\Octave-3.6.4\include\octave-3.6.4\octave--->Includ. Dir.,
2. C:\Software\Octave-3.6.4\include--->Includ. Dir.
3. C:\Software\Octave-3.6.4\lib--->Lib. Dir.
4. C:\Software\Octave-3.6.4\lib\octave\3.6.4--->Lib Dir.
5. I also added 1 and 2 to Additional Inc Dir!!
6. C:\Software\Octave-3.6.4\lib\octave\3.6.4--->Additional Lib. Dir in Linker.

First, I got this error that it cannot find math.h in Program Files while this file was in my Program Files (x86). So, I changed it to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\math.h and it solved this error. However, now I get this error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall octave_value::~octave_value(void)" (__imp_??1octave_value@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void * __thiscall octave_value::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_Eoctave_value@@QAEPAXI@Z)
```

Comment: The `system("PAUSE");` isn't necessary to run the program. You run the program using "Debug"/"Start Without Debugging" to get rid of that ridiculous line.

Comment: Again the same error !

Comment: Well it's a comment to a detail not an answer. It did promise to be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not sufficient to add the library path to the project.

You have to add the library name(s) (including `.lib`) to the "Additional Dependencies" in the Linker/Input tab.

*Edit*

To verify what library has been searched you can enable the Linker/General/Show Progress option. Then you can see in the Build Output what library has actually be used in symbol search.

*Edit*

Your example code doesn't show any instance of an array of `octave_value` instances. So it's a bit surprising that you need to link with any library with the code you've shown. But anyway you want to have these externals resolved.

If there is no other resource (manual, ...) you should detect where the `octave_value` class is implemented. This can be a static library or a DLL.

You can detect the DLL implementation with a `dumpbin /exports` on the DLLs. In that case you need the corresponding import libraries. The LIB should have the same base name as the DLL. Verify that you have added that dependency and how the linker searches this library for symbols.

The name of the symbols `__imp_??1octave_value@@QAE@XZ` indicates that it should be in a DLL. But since you have a problem you might want to search LIBs too.
You can detect the LIB implementation with a `dumpbin /symbols`. In that case you have to add the LIB directly. Again verify it with the Build Output.

The dumpbin output will probably very verbose. You should use either `findstr` to limit the output or redirect the output to a file and search the symbols with an editor of your choice.

Search for `ocatave_value`. If you find a different decoration of the constructor and destructor you might have missed to set an option. A preprocessore directory could be used to define how the library is use. E.g. if you find `octave_value::octave_value` without the `__imp_` prefix you have accidentily compiled for a DLL version altough the class is implemented in a static library. In that case, read the manual and ask at the octave mailing list forum or whatever.

Comment: I added all of the libs and again get the same error !! (octave.lib
octinterp.lib
cruft.lib
blas.lib
dirent.lib
fftw3.lib
fftw3f.lib
gfortran-msvc.lib
gfortran-msvc-static.lib
hdf5.lib
lapack.lib
mingwcompat.lib
msvcmath.lib
ncurses.lib
readline.lib
z.lib)

Comment: Unofrtunately I cannot find any useful information based on this output

Comment: Probably you want to try the pre-built version at mention in the http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Microsoft_Windows#Alternative

Comment: I had done that before. The problem is that there is no manual on how one should use Octave in C++.

Comment: @Sam sure there is. It's a section on the [octave manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html)

Comment: @carandraug This uses `mkoctfile`. Does this work with the desired environment (VS2010)?

Comment: mkoctfile is just a script that handles the required flags for the compilation. I'm not a windows user, so not sure about your answer. But if @Sam reads the man page for mkoctfile, there is an option to print the used flags. He then can use them himself in whatever environment he wants.